# Integration limits in a triple integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I'm having trouble describing a region in space.

Let $B$ the region bounded by the planes $x=0$, $y=0$, $z=0$, $x+y=1$, $z=x+y$. One way of calculating the volume of B is:

\begin{equation}
V(B)=\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1-x} \int_{0}^{x+y}dzdydx=\frac{1}{3}
\end{equation}

I'm trying to change the order to integration to $\int \int \int dxdydz$, but I can't get my integration limits to work (I get different values for the volume).

I thought that $(0<z<1)$, and $(z-y<x<1-y)$, but I can't find the limits on the Y axis. I believe it sould be something like:

\begin{equation}
\int_0^1\int_?^?\int_{z-y}^{1-y}dxdydz
\end{equation}

Comment: Why would you want to switch to that order of integration?

Comment: The book doesn't ask the reader to change the order of integration, but I'm just curious. Also, I'm studying, since I find region description to be kind of hard.

Comment: It's very fiddly, that, as you'll have to find the intersection of the two _slanted_  planes & divide the region up into parts having certain of their edges along that line of intersection.

Comment: The plane z=x+y cuts off a _pyramid_ from the unit box having vertices 000, 001, 101, 011 (ie containing the _corner_ 001); and the plane x+y=1 cuts the unit box into two triangular _prisms_ aligned along the z-axis & sharing vertices 010, 100, 011, 101.

Comment: It's relatively easy to just see it geometrically: the plane x+y=1 cuts the cube equally into two, so that you're left with half it's volume; and then cutting-off that corner by the plane z=x+y takes-off a volume ⅙of the unit cube from _that_; so you're left with ⅓. But then ... how to formulate that as _the limits_ of a triple-integral ... !?

Comment: I think I would just _cheat_ & define a new variable _r_ that is distance _diagonally_ - at angle π/4 to the x-axis and to the y & parallel to the z=0 plane, and do the integral in terms of that! It _might_ be acceptible if you formulate it rigorously enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to work it out from the hints before reading the spoilers.

The first hint is to make a sketch of the cross-section of a plane $z=c$ with the volume of interest and $c$ some constant for which $0 \leq c \leq 1$. What is the shape of this cross-section?

> Answer : a trapezoid, bounded by $x \geq 0, x+y\geq z, y \geq 0, 1 \geq x+y$
>
> Can you now find the integration limits?
>
> > Did you think of splitting the area in two parts to make it easier?
> >
> > > The simplest way would be to split the trapezoid in a parallelogram and a triangle separated by the line $y=c$. Can you solve the problem for both these areas?
> > >
> > > > $$ 
> > > > \int_0^1 d z \left\{ \int_0^z d y \int_{z-y}^{1-x} d x + \int_z^1 d y \int_0^{1-y} d x \right\} = \frac{1}{3}
> > > > $$
> > > >         Obviously not the easiest way to evaluate the integral, but not too difficult either.

Answer (score 0):

That suggestion I made to 'cheat': it's not necessary - the 'fog' has lifted, and I can see now that $$\int_{x=0}^1\int_{y=0}^{1-x}\int_{z=0}^{x+y}dz.dy.dx$$ *does actually* comprise the whole of the volume specified. If you see it through, you get $$\int_{x=0}^1\int_{y=0}^{1-x}(x+y)dy.dx$$$$=$$$$\int_{x=0}^1{1\over2}(2x(1-x)+(1-x)^2)dx$$$$=$$$${1\over2}\int_{x=0}^1(1-x^2)dx$$$$=$$$${1\over3} .$$ It is of course *necessary* to do it this way if you are integrating some function of $x$ $y$ & $z$ over the region - which is *generally* the case when triple integrals arise in natural course ... the geometric shortcut that I broached in the comments can only be used for finding the volume ... except perhaps in the occasional problem having *extraordinary* symmetry.

I think my 'cheat' is still relevant though. Because of the shape & orientation, a more 'fitting' set of coordinates for the integral would be $$r=x+y$$&$$s=x-y ,$$& $z$ kept as it is, whence the integral would be$$\int_{r=0}^1\int_{s=-r}^r\int_{z=0}^r \operatorname{f}({r+s\over2}, {r-s\over2},z).dz.{ds\over\sqrt{2}}.{dr\over\sqrt{2}} ,$$ with the factors of $1/\sqrt{2}$ at the differentials $dr$ & $ds$ so that they represent distance in this space. It might also fit the *function being integrated* over that region better also, as if the region has that shape & orientation, there's an appreciable likelyhood that the function also has some convenient symmetry with respect to that orientation.